# How to create a tag box with html , css and javascript without using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

Does anyone has an example of a tag box with html css and javascript code?
BTW I cant use jquery that isn't allowed in China

Greets,

Comment: jQuery isn't allowed in China? Why can't you simply download a copy of the jQuery code than? Also, please always show what you tried in resolving your own problem. Create a [mcve]

Comment: Do they allow you to code ?

Comment: I meant the google or cloudflare jquery

Comment: @sterrek I don't think you will be prosecuted if you download the latest version and you host it on your server ;) jQuery *is* JS after all.

Comment: China is infamous for banning virtually everything, but why would jQuery be banned?

Comment: what type of box you require ?